# Image's are loading with black background

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am loading image from web-service in dynamic horizontal linear layout .Some of the phones showing images with black background like MOtO-X  with android4.4.4 see the image below

[image]

But on the MOTO-E with android 4.4.4 .its showing image correctly check the image below [image]

Comment: Please add sample image URL in the question. Is it transparent PNG?

Comment: i thinks background is using your Phone's Default Theme Color .... try by changing theme or ... apply color in your Dynamic Code

Comment: layout is being created with code as just used the horizontal scroll view in xml to hold this layout

Comment: @situee yes images are transparent

Comment: @ koutuk i tried changing the Default Theme Color but it didn't worked BTw i have used Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Share possible code too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ImageView, use ImageButton and set android:src as image and background color as transparent/white.

Answer (score 0):

Set ImageView background white color.

```
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
```